# What is the word to describe something more incredible than being merely incredible?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, vocabulary

For instance, Riemann mapping theorem is more than just incredible: merely using the word 'incredible' to describe it is not enough. So, what is more incredible than incredible?

Comment: Why is *incredible* not enough? It has an absolute meaning, i.e. not-believable, so I find it hard to see how you could go beyond that. If you want to describe *why* it is not-believable, you could try *[absurd](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/absurd?q=absurd)*, but a bit of context and an explanation of why *incredible* is insufficient would greatly improve your question.

Comment: Ingenious. Evolution is the ingenious mechanism of nature to produce its own persistent eternal companion.

Comment: Either something is credible or it is not.

Comment: @PrestonFitzgerald There are degrees of credibility.

Comment: incrediburgable!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Paradoxical** (*seemingly* impossible)?

**Counter-intuitive** - not as string but certainly apt for your example.

And **unbelievable** - is means exactly the same as incredible, but it may have some stronger connotations because the link to stronger forms of *beliefs* is more obvious.

You could use an actual *hyperbole*: **impossible**!

Answer (score 3):

[image: inconceivable]

**Inconceivable** unbelievable; incredible.

Comment: You keep using that word.

Answer (score 1):

Riemann mapping theorem is *extraordinary*.

Alternately, consider such colloquialisms as *mind-boggling* and *unreal*.

> [mind-boggling](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mind-boggling): having a powerful or overwhelming effect on the mind
>
> **unreal**: so remarkable as to elicit disbelief; fantastic; unbelievable

Answer (score 1):

I suppose **uncountenanceable** means 'not even admitting of consideration that [it] might be possible'. It's rare enough to be self-emphasising. But it doesn't fit as a descriptor for a theory, of course.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the expression  "**beyond human knowledge**" to give the idea of something really difficult to conceive.

Answer (score 0):

For these cases I normally use "**mind-blowing**" E.g. "The multiverse theory is just mind-blowing"

Answer (score 0):

I think **phenomenal** is more than incredible.  You might be an incredible basketball player but only a few are phenoms.

> adjective:  exceedingly or unbelievably great

If you just can't believe something because it is so incredible then it is **incredulous**.

> adjective:  not disposed or willing to believe; unbelieving

And in the very rare cases, the word we might reserve for the **other-worldly**, is **preposterous**.

> extremely unreasonable or silly

Comment: [adjective: not disposed or willing to believe; unbelieving] "If you just can't believe something because it is so incredible then it is incredulous." Oh, hell no!! According to the definition you supplied: If you just can't believe something because it is so incredible then YOU ARE incredulous.

Answer (score -1):

Try *superlatively incredible.*​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​